# Python3 Tkinter - Button to increase entry box value by float such as 1.0 then update entry box display

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a few buttons that appends a float value to the current value in a tkinter entry box.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk

menu = Tk()
menu.geometry('800x480')
frame1 = Frame(menu) 
frame1.grid()

#entry box
e1 = Entry(frame1)
e1.insert(0, float("1.0")) 
e1.grid(row=2, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

#buttons
bt1 = Button(frame1, text="Add 1.0")
bt1.grid() 
bt2 = Button(frame1, text="Add 0.1")
bt2.grid()
bt3 = Button(frame1, text="Add 0.01")
bt3.grid()
```

For example, suppose the current value in e1 is 1.0. I would like to create a button that adds 1.0 to the current value (turning it to 2.0 and display that instead of 1.0). I would also like to make buttons that add the value 0.1, and 0.01. What is the best approach to do this? Currently I am looking at using counter but I am not quite sure how to implement it.

To visualize what I mean in case I am not explaining it well basically I have the current setup [before the button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxOoy.jpg). Suppose I click add 1.0 I want [the 1.0 to turn into 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qAXd.jpg).

Comment: BTW: instead of `float("1.0")` you can use `1.0`.

Comment: use `Button(..., command=...)`,  `e1.get()`, `float(...)`, add value, `e1.inset(...)` . If you realy need you can keep value in some `variable` as float and then you don't need `e1.get()` and `float()` because you add to variable and put it  in entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `command=` to assign function to button. This function have to get text from Entry, convert to float, add 0.1, (delete all text in Entry), insert new value into Entry,

```
import tkinter as tk

def add_1_0():
    value = float(e1.get())
    value += 1.0
    e1.delete(0, 'end')
    e1.insert(0, value)

def add_0_1():
    value = float(e1.get())
    value += 0.1
    e1.delete(0, 'end')
    e1.insert(0, value)

def add_0_01():
    value = float(e1.get())
    value += 0.01
    e1.delete(0, 'end')
    e1.insert(0, value)

root = tk.Tk()

#entry box
e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.insert(0, 1.0) 
e1.pack()

#buttons
bt1 = tk.Button(root, text="Add 1.0", command=add_1_0)
bt1.pack() 
bt2 = tk.Button(root, text="Add 0.1", command=add_0_1)
bt2.pack()
bt3 = tk.Button(root, text="Add 0.01", command=add_0_01)
bt3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

You can put repeated code in one function

```
def add_1_0():
    add(1.0)

def add_0_1():
    add(0.1)

def add_0_01():
    add(0.01)

def add(val):
    value = float(e1.get())
    value += val
    e1.delete(0, 'end')
    e1.insert(0, value)
```

---

If you have code in one function then you can use `lambda` to assign function with arguments.

```
import tkinter as tk

def add(val):
    value = float(e1.get())
    value += val
    e1.delete(0, 'end')
    e1.insert(0, value)

root = tk.Tk()

#entry box
e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.insert(0, 1.0) 
e1.pack()

#buttons
bt1 = tk.Button(root, text="Add 1.0", command=lambda:add(1.0))
bt1.pack() 
bt2 = tk.Button(root, text="Add 0.1", command=lambda:add(0.1))
bt2.pack()
bt3 = tk.Button(root, text="Add 0.01", command=lambda:add(0.01))
bt3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was trying to do. However, when trying to use 
def add_0_1():   I am having an issue, for example. If I click it once it goes from 1.0 to 1.1, which is great. But if I click it again it goes from 1.1 to 1.2000000000000002

Comment: it is normal behaver of float values. There is infinite number of float values  but computer can't keep all values using only 64bit - so it keeps only approximation. It can't keep `1.2` so you see value which it keeps. And it gives problem because `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3` see more on page http://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Okay thank you. I did not know that was an issue. For now I'm just going to use {0:.2f} to format it to display it nicely. I appreciate your help