# Tkinter While loop int issue

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

```
import time
from tkinter import* 

start_value=Entry(root,width=10)
start_value.pack()
start_value.get()

while int(start_value.get())<100:
   int(start_value.get()) += 1
```

Because of the ***int(start_value.get()) += 1*** on this code my loop doesn't work.

Comment: This is not how you increment `start_value`

Comment: This question shows how to increment an `Entry` value. [Python3 Tkinter - Button to increase entry box value by float such as 1.0 then update entry box display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605334/python3-tkinter-button-to-increase-entry-box-value-by-float-such-as-1-0-then-u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
import string
from tracemalloc import start
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import numpy as np
import random
import win32api, win32con
import math
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*    

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x550+50+100")
root.title("Led Controler by Yağız Arslan")

print("system is online")





def buttonclick12():
    start_value_int = start_value.get()
    end_value_int=end_value.get()
    print(start_value_int)
    print(end_value_int)
    loop_number=int(end_value_int) + 1
    loop_total= int(start_value_int)
    
    while int(loop_number) > int(loop_total) :
        print("NFT_" +str(loop_total) + " generated")  
        loop_total += 1 




start_value=Entry(root,width=10)
start_value.pack()

end_value=Entry(root,width=10)
end_value.pack()

#loop_number =  
collection_name=Entry(root,width=10)
collection_name.pack()
price=Entry(root,width=10)
button1=Button(root,text="Start",command=buttonclick12)
button1.pack()
loop_total = 0


        


root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

the issue arises from the fact that you are creating an Entry, which you are assigning as an empty string. So, when you try to convert start_value into an int, you are trying to convert an empty string into an int, hence the error. You can fix this by setting the initial value of the entry to 0 (or whatever int you want), incrementing that value, deleting the initial value, and then reinserting the new value. I have provided an example of the entry value incrementing on its own until it reaches 100.

```
import time
from tkinter import* 

root = Tk()

start_value=Entry(root,width=10)
start_value.pack()
start_value.insert(0, 0)

def increase_value():
    value = int(start_value.get())
    value += 1
    start_value.delete(0, 'end')
    start_value.insert(0, value)

    if value < 100:
        # increase the value every 100 milliseconds
        root.after(100, increase_value)

increase_value()

root.mainloop()
```